# importing stuff into my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse, if I needed to grab a .java file or a png or an xml file into a directory, I would simply right click on the directory, click import, find the file, hit return and I had the file.

How can I do the same in Android Studio?  There is no import function in the context menu.  The File menu just has import functionality for projects and modules.
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Drag & drop into appropriate folder?

Answer (score 0):

Right click - copy file.
Right click in AS in the directory you want the file - paste